# How to export multiple tables to an excel spreadsheet with microsoft access

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have 2 tables in access from which data have to be exported to a spreadsheeet. Is this possible to be performed using the "DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet" query? The code is given below for reference.

```
Call CreatePieChart("julydupscores", "julyapvscores", "C:\Performance Database\graph123.xlsm")

'FUNCTION

Public Sub CreatePieChart(sSource As String, qSource As String, msFileName As String)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel97, sSource, msFileName, False
```

How can I transfer qsource(the second source) too?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I transfer qsource(the second source) too?

Not knowing what "magic" your `graph123.xlsm` does, it's impossible to say for sure, but in general you would just add a second `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` statement specifying `qSource` as the source. When exporting to Excel (recent versions, at least) if you specify the same Excel filename then the second table will be added as another tab on the existing Excel document. (If you want them in separate files, then specify a different Excel filename.)